# how to remove button background in extjs?

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to remove button background color?actually i can remove by using image,but the problem is image wont gives the toggle Handler,
i am getting like ![enter image description here][1] and i need to remove white background as it ,please anybody help me!..
         `

```
{
            icon        :   'filter-image',
            scale       :   'large',
            frame           :       false,
                        //body Style    :   'background:none',
                        //style         :       'background-color:blue',
            border          :       false,
            id      :   'tzar-filter-button',
            enable Toggle   :   true,
            toggle Group    :   'toggle-icons',
            toggle Handler  :   function(button, state){
                if(state){

                }else{

                }
            }
        }
`
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
text: 'Click me',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
enableToggle   :   true,
id:'btn',
style:'background:none;',
toggleHandler  :   
           function(button, state){
             if(state){
                document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor="Red";
             }else{
                document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor="Green";
             }
           }
});
```